# May Composition of a strictly monotonic and a measurable functions be unmeasurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm interested to know that is there any strictly monotonic function like g and a lebesgue measurable set E, such that $g^{-1}(E)$ be not Lebesgue measurable. I think it should exist but I couldn't construct it. I will be happy if someone here help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "strongly monotonic" you mean "strictly monotonic", i.e. (in the increasing case) $x < y$ implies $g(x) < g(y)$.   Yes, there is.  Let
$M$ be any non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.  There is a strictly monotonic
function $g$ from $[0,1]$ into the Cantor set.  Then $E = g(M)$ is Lebesgue measurable because it has measure $0$, but $g^{-1}(E) = M$ is non-measurable.